# Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm developing a program using Springboot for the Backend, JavaFX for the Frontend. I use Unirest to use the API REST. Everything's been working fine for now, but i'm encountering a problem that i don't know how to solve.
I have a class called 'Avviso', (which translates to 'notice'), and it has some fields like sender (string), body(string) and a LocalDate and LocalTime, to store the information of 'when was the notices sent'.

When i do this call:

```
            Type avvisoListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Avviso>>(){}.getType();

            ArrayList<Avviso> avvisi = new Gson().fromJson(apiResponse.getBody().toString(), avvisoListType);

            return avvisi;
```

It gives me this error.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/karlo/Downloads/Nuovo%20FrontEnd/Ratatouille23_Desktop-Nuovo_MVC_Pi-_Logico/target/classes/homepage-admin.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2673)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/karlo/Downloads/Nuovo%20FrontEnd/Ratatouille23_Desktop-Nuovo_MVC_Pi-_Logico/target/classes/gestisci-avvisi.fxml

    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.HomepageController.loadGestisciAvvisi(HomepageController.java:36)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.HomepageController.<init>(HomepageController.java:23)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Controller.Supervisore.HomepageSupervisoreController.<init>(HomepageSupervisoreController.java:24)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Controller.Amministratore.HomepageAdminController.<init>(HomepageAdminController.java:28)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.View.Admin.HomepageAdminView.initialize(HomepageAdminView.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/karlo/Downloads/Nuovo%20FrontEnd/Ratatouille23_Desktop-Nuovo_MVC_Pi-_Logico/target/classes/gestisci-avvisi.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.HomepageController.loadGestisciAvvisi(HomepageController.java:32)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@19/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@19/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2673)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.time.LocalDate#year' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:160)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:294)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1226)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1137)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1047)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1014)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Model.DAO.DAOImplUnirest.AvvisoDAOImplUnirest.getAvvisi(AvvisoDAOImplUnirest.java:28)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.Controller.GestisciAvvisiController.ottieniAvviso(GestisciAvvisiController.java:36)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.View.GestisciAvvisiView.popolaAvvisiAccordion(GestisciAvvisiView.java:40)
    at com.example.ratatouille23/com.example.ratatouille23.View.GestisciAvvisiView.initialize(GestisciAvvisiView.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final int java.time.LocalDate.year accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to module com.google.gson
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:387)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:363)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)
    ... 52 more
Exception running application com.example.ratatouille23.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

After this, i have tried to open java.time to com.google.gson in module-info.java (and obviously, i required java.base before), but when i addedd this, i obtaint the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: <mymodule>
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package java.base not found in module

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using the latest version of com.google.code.gson, the 2.10.1.

Comment: According to [this issue (`github.com`)](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1507#issuecomment-1327903023), it looks like the support for [JSR 310 (`jcp.org`)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is missing. The issue discussion contains a possible fix.

Comment: @Turing85 i cant get it to work and i would prefer solving this issue with gson instead of using another method just for this situation.

Comment: By the way… To record a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use `Instant`, not the `Local…` classes. You need the context of an offset or time zone to determine a moment.